# Ajax Call not storing data in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

The following code is not storing values in the Array

```
var checkListIdForEmail= new Array();

    var checkListNameforEmail;
     function getCheckListIdAndName() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'URL/' + 12464,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                for (var i=0; i< result.length;i++) {
                   $('#checkListIdForEmail').val(result.checklistDetailId[i]);
                }
                // alert("Success");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Errror while getting header values");
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know what needs to store all data in an array..

Thank You

Comment: any sample data?

Comment: is the result already an array?

Comment: {
        "$id": "1",
        "checklistDetailId": 39956,
        "checklistName": "XYZ",
        "formNo": 12464,
        "Comments": "",
        "summaryResult": "Pending"
    }

Comment: It is data of array index[0]

Comment: so it is already an array

Comment: i've posted an answer. please check

Comment: that's because you never do anything with the var `checkListIdForEmail` - `#checkListIdForEmail` has nothing to do with `var checkListIdForEmail`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest on your success callback, do this instead.

```
success: function (result) {
checkListIdForEmail = result;
},
```

since result is already an array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want to store to the checkListIdForEmail array:

```
for (var i=0; i< result.length;i++) {
   checkListIdForEmail[i] = result[i].checklistDetailId;           
}
$('#checkListIdForEmail').val(checkListIdForEmail);
```